# how to move my header through the body

Tags: html, css

I want to make my header move through the main part as the user scroll it down. I tried `position:fixed` but it didnt work, what do you suggest?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
        .header
        {
            height:6.14%;
            width:auto;
            background:red;
            position:fixed;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .headerIn
        {
            height:35px;
            width:auto;
            background:#666;
        }
        .main
        {
            width:auto;
            height:12000px;
            margin:0px 0px 0px 25px;
            padding:0px;
            border:2px #36F solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="headerIn"><div class="header"></div></div>
<div class="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain the desired behaviour please.

Comment: the thing is in the header i wanna put the account stuff , and i want it to stay On top even when the user scrolls the page :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/vN89e/12/

```
.headerIn {
    height:35px;
    width: 100%;
    background:#666;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.main {
    margin: 35px 0 0 25px;
    border:2px #36F solid;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Only the border is moving when scrolling it should not.

Comment: i wanned to put some info in the .headerIn and i wanned it to scroll and your answer is doing it well

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.header{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.header {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use position fixed, but you have to set the value of top to zero. Absolute positioning will attach it to the top of the page, but won't allow the header to scroll through the entire page.

```
.header
    {
        height:6.14%;
        width:auto;
        background:red;
        position:fixed;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: well the thing is the z-index One worked and i got what i wanned , but this One isnt working...